# Como puedo hacer un pop up que se cierre despues de x segundos en Selenium de Python, ejecutando javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, popup

Estoy tratando de hacer un script que utiliza Selenium para refrescar una pagina despues de cierto tiempo y es necesario que el usuario no entre a un link diferente antes de que se ejecute la accion, por lo que quiero hacer un pop up que desaparezca luego de 10 segundos pero que avise al usuario de no entrar a ningun link diferente.

Como puedo hacer algo asi ejecutando el script the JS desde Python?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función time.sleep de la biblioteca estándar de Python para hacer que el script se detenga durante unos segundos antes de continuar con el siguiente paso. Para mostrar un pop-up en la página web, puedes usar la función alert de JavaScript.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esto usando Selenium en Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Abrimos el navegador y vamos a la página deseada
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Mostramos un pop-up usando la función alert de JavaScript
driver.execute_script("alert('No entres a ningún link diferente antes de que se ejecute la acción')")

# Esperamos 10 segundos
time.sleep(10)

# Cerramos el pop-up
driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function(e){};")
```

En este ejemplo, abrimos un navegador y vamos a la página deseada usando Selenium. Luego, usamos la función execute_script para ejecutar un script de JavaScript que muestra un pop-up usando la función alert. Después, esperamos 10 segundos usando la función time.sleep de Python. Finalmente, cerramos el pop-up usando otra llamada a execute_script, que cancela el evento onbeforeunload que se ejecuta cuando se intenta cerrar la página.

Espero que esto te ayude a implementar lo que necesitas. Si tienes alguna pregunta o necesitas más ayuda, no dudes en preguntar.